# how to implement fast spellchecker in Python with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spell-checking

I work on text mining problem and need to extract all mentioned of certain keywords. For example, given the list:

```
list_of_keywords = ['citalopram', 'trazodone', 'aspirin']
```

I need to find all occurrences of the keywords in a text. That could be easily done with Pandas (assuming my text is read in from a csv file):

import pandas as pd

```
df_text = pd.read_csv('text.csv')
df_text['matches'] = df_text.str.findall('|'.join(list_of_keywords))
```

However, there are spelling mistakes in the text and some times my keywords will be written as:

```
'citalopram' as 'cetalopram'
```

or

```
'trazodone' as 'trazadon'
```

Searching on the web, I found some suggestions how to implement the [spell checker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), but I am not sure where to insert the spell checker and I reckon that it may slow down the search in the case a very large text.

As another option, it has been suggested to use a wild card with regex and insert in the potential locations of confusion (**conceptually** written)

```
.findall('c*t*l*pr*m')
```

However I am not convinced that I can capture all possible problematic cases. I tried some out-of-the-box spell checkers, but my texts are some-what specific and I need a spell checker that 'knows' my domain (medical domain).

**QUESTION**

Is there any efficient way to extract keywords from a text including spelling mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, you cannot capture all possible misspellings with regular expressions.

You do however have options.

You could

- Use a [trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structure-dictionary-spell-checker/). A lot of auto complete and spell checking solutions use tries. However most of them operate on a word for word basis. Not on text as a whole
- That being said, what you really want is a fuzzy text extractor as you just want to match alternate/slightly wrong spellings and not correct those spellings in the text. So you have more options here as well

  - Computational genomics has this challenge where they want to search for patterns of base pairs in long sequences. They allow for a certain amount of mismatch in the matched text. So an approximate matching solution like the ones outlined [here](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~langmea/resources/lecture_notes/approximate_matching.pdf) will help. Those slides have excellent use of the pigeon hole principle to do what you need and the code is open source too!
  - If you want something a lot less complex, just run an edit distance filter on all the words of the doc and admit only words with an edit distance of `k` or less.

**To expand on what I mean by Edit Distance**

(Images/Code borrowed from slides linked above, slides are free to use for anyone i.e no license)

Let us examine a simpler concept of ***Hamming Distance***

```
def hammingDistance(x,  y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    nmm = 0
    for i in xrange(0,  len(x)):
        if x[i] != y[i]:
            nmm += 1
    return nmm
```

Hamming distance returns the number of characters that must swapped between 2 equal length strings to make them equal.

But what happens when the strings are not equal length?

Use *editDistance* Which is the num of characters that must be swapped/inserted/deleted on 2 strings to make them equal

Hamming distance becomes the base case for a recursive algorithm now

```
def edDistRecursive(x, y):
    if len(x) == 0: return len(y)
    if len(y) == 0: return len(x)
    delt = 1 if x[-1] != y[-1] else 0
    diag = edDistRecursive(x[:-1], y[:-1]) + delt
    vert = edDistRecursive(x[:-1], y) + 1
    horz = edDistRecursive(x, y[:-1]) + 1
    return min(diag, vert, horz)
```

Just call the func above on what you think the word would/should match to (maybe by first looking up a trie). You can even memoize the soln to make it faster as there is a high probability for overlap

Comment: thanks! I like your suggestions and definitely will try them. I think, given the large amount of text I need to process, computing a distance should be sufficient (also inspired by Peter Norvig implementation). I need to play around and actually test how fast it is. I will u[date on my progress!

Comment: Of course :) and good luck! You could also experiment with Levenshtein distance :)